# Create new column based on if rows from 2 data frames match

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, dplyr

This seems simple enough, but can't figure it out. I'd like to create a new column in **`df2`** (`impute_id`) that identifies whether or not the value (`measurement`) was imputed or if it is the raw, observed value from **`df1`**. If the rows match, then in the new column in **`df2`**, `impute_id`, assign the string `observed` and if the rows do not match, then assign the string `imputed`. I'd like to do this using `dplyr` if possible. Also to note, the rows in the data frames may not be in the same order even though they are in the example.

---

**Example**

*Raw data*

```
df1
   time protocol     measurement_type sample measurement
1     0     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a     0.57561
2     0     HPLC            D-Glucose      a          NA
3     0     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a          NA
4     0     HPLC            D-Glucose      b          NA
5     0    OD600      Optical Density      b     0.14430
6    22     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      b          NA
7    22     HPLC            D-Glucose      a          NA
8    22    OD600      Optical Density      a          NA
9    24     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a          NA
10   24     HPLC            D-Glucose      b    33.95529
```

*Imputed Data*

```
df2
   time protocol     measurement_type sample measurement
1     0     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a     0.57561
2     0     HPLC            D-Glucose      a    33.95529
3     0     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a     0.57561
4     0     HPLC            D-Glucose      b    33.95529
5     0    OD600      Optical Density      b     0.14430
6    22     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      b     0.57561
7    22     HPLC            D-Glucose      a    33.95529
8    22    OD600      Optical Density      a     0.14430
9    24     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a     0.57561
10   24     HPLC            D-Glucose      b    33.95529
```

---

**Desired Output**

```
df2
   time protocol     measurement_type sample measurement  impute_id
1     0     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a     0.57561   observed
2     0     HPLC            D-Glucose      a    33.95529    imputed
3     0     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a     0.57561    imputed
4     0     HPLC            D-Glucose      b    33.95529    imputed
5     0    OD600      Optical Density      b     0.14430   observed
6    22     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      b     0.57561    imputed
7    22     HPLC            D-Glucose      a    33.95529    imputed
8    22    OD600      Optical Density      a     0.14430    imputed
9    24     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a     0.57561    imputed
10   24     HPLC            D-Glucose      b    33.95529   observed
```

**Reproducible Data**

*Raw Data*

```
df1 <- structure(list(time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 24L, 
24L), protocol = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("HPLC", "OD600"), class = "factor"), measurement_type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("cis,cis-Muconic acid", 
"D-Glucose", "Optical Density"), class = "factor"), sample = c("a", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b"), measurement = c(0.57561, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.1443, NA, NA, NA, NA, 33.95529)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

*Imputed Data*

```
df2 <- structure(list(time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 24L, 
24L), protocol = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("HPLC", "OD600"), class = "factor"), measurement_type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("cis,cis-Muconic acid", 
"D-Glucose", "Optical Density"), class = "factor"), sample = c("a", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b"), measurement = c(0.57561, 
33.95529, 0.57561, 33.95529, 0.1443, 0.57561, 33.95529, 0.1443, 
0.57561, 33.95529)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(measurement_type) %>%
  mutate(impute_id = ifelse(is.na(measurement), "imputed", "observed"),
         measurement = min(measurement, na.rm = TRUE))

   time protocol     measurement_type sample measurement  impute_id
1     0     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a     0.57561 observed
2     0     HPLC            D-Glucose      a    33.95529  imputed
3     0     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a     0.57561  imputed
4     0     HPLC            D-Glucose      b    33.95529  imputed
5     0    OD600      Optical Density      b     0.14430 observed
6    22     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      b     0.57561  imputed
7    22     HPLC            D-Glucose      a    33.95529  imputed
8    22    OD600      Optical Density      a     0.14430  imputed
9    24     HPLC cis,cis-Muconic acid      a     0.57561  imputed
10   24     HPLC            D-Glucose      b    33.95529 observed
```